# .net - Sql function SUM() changes column name

Tags: sql, .net, odbc

I use SQL via ODBC to query an excel file from a .net application. When I use the following statement

```
 query = "SELECT DISTINCT [registration$].article, [registration$].No, SUM([registration$].quantity) FROM [registration$] WHERE [registration$].No NOT LIKE '%ATD%' GROUP BY [registration$].article, [registration$].No, [registration$].quantity"
```

It works, but after this query the column name is "expr1002" and not amount.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: In the SQL server?

Comment: @jishansiddique No, as written, I directly query an excel file.

Comment: Remove `[registration$].quantity` from the `GROUP BY`. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.) Also, the GROUP BY will not return any duplicate rows, so no need to do SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: `SUM(column_name)` is an expression like any other. It happens to only refer to one column, but is *not* the column itself. The database engine recognizes it as an expression and assigns a column name of "expr____" because you have not specified the column name you would like. This should not be terribly surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use column alias

```
SUM([registration$].quantity) AS [quantity]
```